# Pass response body from IDispatchMessageInspector to Application_EndRequest

Tags: wcf, rest, global-asax, idispatchmessageinspector

I want to log the request parameters and response body that traffics thru my WCF REST service . I can access full response in IDispatchMessageInspector. And I can access request headers and other items that I store in Context.Items during the operations in Application_EndRequest.

During my debugging, I see the operations goes thru IDispatchMessageInspector and then thru Application_EndRequest. My idea is to store the response somewhere in IDispatchMessageInspector and then in Application_EndRequest, I'll retrieve the response and log it together with other request parameters.

So my question is: **Where should I store the response so it's accessible in Application_EndRequest?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently trying to do something similar.  I am logging an incoming request, storing it in the database and would then like to pass the log ID to my endpoint for use later.  In your *AfterReceiveRequest* call, simply add whatever you need to the IncomingMessageProperties attribute of the current operationcontext:

**Edit: Fixed the code below**

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        request = buffer.CreateMessage();
        int LogRequestID = Logging.LogIncomingRequest(buffer.CreateMessage());

        OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.Add("LogRequestID", LogRequestID);

        return null;
    }
```

I can then read the LogRequestID in my endpoint with the following code:

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["LogRequestID"]
```

You can also pass a more complex if you need to.  Hope that helps.